# Refresh only content using UpdatePanel control

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Is it possible to use UpdatePanel control with navigating through the left panel (menu)?
In Main.master there are left menu

```
<dx:ASPxNavBar ID="ASPxNavBar1" runat="server" AutoCollapse="True" EnableAnimation="True" Width="100%">
    <dx:NavBarGroup Text="Group">
        <Items>
            <dx:NavBarItem  NavigateUrl="Content/Content1.aspx" Text="Content1"></dx:NavBarItem>
            <dx:NavBarItem NavigateUrl="Content/Content2.aspx" Text="Data Subject"></dx:NavBarItem>
        </Items>
    </dx:NavBarGroup>
</dx:ASPxNavBar>
```

and I'm trying to use refresh only content using UpdatePanel control

```
<div class="contentPane">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" updatemode="conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work; header and menu still reloading when navigating through the menu.

*Content1.aspx* and *Content2.aspx* files have just an usual content inside of `<asp:content>` tag

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="PK" Width="750px">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButtonInHeader="True" VisibleIndex="0" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True">
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="PK" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" VisibleIndex="1">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" VisibleIndex="2">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        </Columns>
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you are using an *UpdatePanel* is that a requeriment?
I would use an [ASPxCallbackPanel](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxMultiUseControlsDemos/CallbackPanel/Example.aspx) which is a **great** replacement for the *UpdatePanel* and you can use it since you are using DevExpress controls

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var postponedCallbackRequired = false;
        function OnListBoxIndexChanged(s, e) {
            if(CallbackPanel.InCallback())
                postponedCallbackRequired = true;
            else
                CallbackPanel.PerformCallback();
        }
        function OnEndCallback(s, e) {
            if(postponedCallbackRequired) {
                CallbackPanel.PerformCallback();
                postponedCallbackRequired = false;
            }
        } 
    </script>

<dx:ASPxListBox runat="server" Height="221px" Width="100%" TextField="Name" DataSourceID="EmployeesDataSource1"
                        ValueField="EmployeeID" ID="ASPxListBox1" ClientInstanceName="ListBox" BackColor="Transparent">
                        <Border BorderWidth="0px"></Border>
                        <ItemStyle>
                            <Border BorderWidth="0px"></Border>
                        </ItemStyle>
                        <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="OnListBoxIndexChanged" />
                    </dx:ASPxListBox>


<dx:ASPxCallbackPanel runat="server" ID="ASPxCallbackPanel1" Height="250px" ClientInstanceName="CallbackPanel" RenderMode="Table">
                        <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="OnEndCallback"></ClientSideEvents>
                        <PanelCollection>
                            <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent3" runat="server">
 </dx:PanelContent>
                        </PanelCollection>
                    </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>
```

You can see a complete sample code [here](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxMultiUseControlsDemos/CallbackPanel/Example.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Victor. This is a very close script for the one I'm looking for. I don't need data binding within `ASPxListBox` and `ASPxCallbackPanel` as the example shows. I already have content in aspx files. I'll investigate whether there are similar solutions with URL list items.

Comment: @corry nice to know it helped